# How To Conform to the Sequence Protocol in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, json-deserialization, jsondecoder, parsing-error

Currently trying to parse a json dictionary to the screen in swift however I'm running into this sequence protocol error, and also a type mismatch error where it gets a string/data and expects a Int. Error is "Type 'ProductResponse' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'" and

> "typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil)], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))"

```
 struct ProductResponse: Codable {
    let code: String
    let product: Product
    let statusVerbose: String
    let status: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, product
        case statusVerbose = "status_verbose"
        case status
    }
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let code: String
    let productName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case productName = "product_name"
    }

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //var products = [Product]()
    let API_URL = "https://carsdata/api/v0/product/5000112630794.json"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request(API_URL).responseJSON {
            response in
            let json = response.data
            do
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let productData = try decoder.decode(ProductResponse.self, from: json!)
                for product in productData{  print(product.productName!) } }
            catch
                let err{  print(err) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. And `productData` is **not** an array.

Comment: I'm confused. To get this error message `code` is supposed to be declared as `Int`.

Comment: That was I was thinking, originally I had nothing declared as an Int @vadian so im confused as to how i got that error. But because I can't build it I cant test it again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is you are not parsing the JSON as it comes. You have two objects here. `ProductResponse` and `Product` and you're trying to parse it as one. `productName` is part of `Product` but you're trying to get it from `ProductResponse`. For clarity, I would recommend you to create 2 entities and try with this:

```
struct ProductResponse: Codable {
    let code: String
    let product: Product
    let statusVerbose: String
    let status: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, product
        case statusVerbose = "status_verbose"
        case status
    }
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let code: String
    let productName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case productName = "product_name"
    }
}
```

And try to decode `ProductResponse.self` instead.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me, however I still get the same error of does not conform to protocol sequence @barbarity coming up on the line below "for product in productData.."

Comment: you don't need `for p in productData{  print(product.productName!) } }` You just do `productData.product.productName`